# How to move image from gallery to application folder directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i am creating application which hiding images from gallery.What i need? I need pick images from gallery and move it to application folder i tried lot of plugin but all is failed to achieve this task i use   wechat_assets_picker: ^8.4.3 plungin for picking up image and photo_manager: ^2.6.0 for moving photo .i am successfully able to copy but unable to moving it.Then i tried solving issue when user pick images from gallery and they copy it to application directory after copy it delete image from gallery but issue is that the delete image go on phone gallery trash i want its permanently remove from gallery. only available in my application directory.Here is my code below.

```
 late List<AssetEntity> selectedAssets;

  Future<void> pickImageAndMove() async {
    List<AssetEntity>? result = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(
      context,
      pickerConfig: const AssetPickerConfig(
        requestType: RequestType.image,
        maxAssets: 20,
      ),
    );

    if (result != null && result.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedAssets = List<AssetEntity>.from(result); // Save the selected assets to the list
      for (var asset in selectedAssets) {
        File? file = await asset.file;
        if (file != null) {
          String path = file.path;
          print('The path: $path');
        }
      }

      // Continue processing the selected images or perform any other operations
    }
  }
```